# Allow the user to add only one event per day over FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)
Is there any way that ban the user to enter another event to the same day if s/he already added an event to that day before ?

So,If the use enters an event on a day,1-1-2012.
If s/he clicks that day again,it will ban the user to enter a new event.
I have an array of objects which contain the events the user enters.
I am thinking now to filter this array and accordingly re-act when the user fires the select event.
Am I on the right track !!
Do you know other way to optimize that !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you are tracking it, you have control of what needs to be done.

Please take a look at:-

[In the FullCalendar dayClick event, can I get the events that already exist in clicked date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516050/in-the-fullcalendar-dayclick-event-can-i-get-the-events-that-already-exist-in-c)

Might help you.

Comment: Thanks that what actually I did and you can find my whole code here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183667/remove-selected-event-from-the-calendar/10287831#10287831

Answer (score 0):

In the version 2.2 of full calendar one can use eventOverlap to control overlapping of events. Refer http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/

And for agenda slotEventOverlap
Refer http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/